# Java Strings - What is the difference between "Java" and new String("Java")?

Tags: java, string, reference, string-pool

Given this example code:

```
class basic {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Java";
        String s2 = new String("Java");
    }
}
```

Are `s1` and `s2` both reference variables of an object?
Do those two lines of code do the same thing?

Comment: `s1` and `s2` are both references, certainly.  Lines 3 and 4 don't do exactly the same thing.  Normally a string literal like "Java" would be comparable with `==` for all other literals in a program.  But calling `new String` forces a new object and the two references are no longer equal with `==`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I tried to edit your question to ask the question directly, and [avoid conversational language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/kind-reminder-to-remove-noise) - this is *not a discussion forum*, thus anything to do with you as a programmer - i.e., not about *the code* - is off topic.

Comment: However, I'm not clear what you mean by "reference variables of an object". They are variables that have an object type (specifically, `java.lang.String`), which (under the hood) store object references. However, we normally just call these "objects", because Java does not let you work with the references "as references" - you only get the objects themselves whenever you interact with the variable. See e.g. https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 3, 4 don't do the same thing, as:

`String s1 = "Java";` may reuse an instance from the [string constant pool](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-constant-pool-in-java/) if one is available, whereas `new String("Java");` creates a new and referentially distinct instance of a String object.

Therefore, Lines 3 and 4 don't do the same thing.

Now, lets have a look at the following code:

```
String s1 = "Java";
String s2 = "Java";

System.out.println(s1 == s2);      // true

s2 = new String("Java");
System.out.println(s1 == s2);      // false
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // true
```

`==` on two reference types is a reference identity comparison. Two objects that are equals are not necessarily `==`. Usually, it is wrong to use `==` on reference types, and most of the time `equals` need to be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing String using a new keyword `String s2 = new String("Java");` creates a new object in the heap of memory. String initialized through this method is mutable means to say the value of the string can be reassigned after initialization.
Whereas, `String s1 = "Java"` direct String initialization using the Literal creates an object in the pooled area of memory. String created through Literal doesn’t create a new object. It just passed the reference to the earlier created object.